# Empty database during android application development

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I've set up a whole database on sqlite3 and copied the file(copy-paste) into the assets folder of my project. Physically, the database folder is present. However when i try to access the database through my code, the logcat say "table-name" doesn't exist.

I've checked my database over and over again in sqlite3 and the mentioned table exists with some data as well.

this is the main Activity:

```
package com.noura.luba;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    TextView forgotPass, createAcc;
    Button loginButton;
    EditText userID, pass;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
             loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

             forgotPass= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordTextView);
             createAcc= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.createAccountTextView);
             loginButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
             userID=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userIDEditText);
             userID.setHint("UserID");
            // pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
             pass = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText)); 
             pass.setHint("Password");
             pass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);


             createAcc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {

                     Intent intentCreateAcc = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateAccActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intentCreateAcc);

                 }
             });

           forgotPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intentForgotPass = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ForgotPassActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intentForgotPass);
            }
             }); 

       //      loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         //      public void onClick(View v) {

           //        String id=userID.getText().toString();

            //       Intent intentLogin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);

                //   intentLogin.putExtra("User_ID", id);
                //   startActivity(intentLogin);

           //    }

          //   }); 

            loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String userName = userID.getText().toString();
                    String password = pass.getText().toString();

                    String storedPassword = loginDataBaseAdapter
                            .getSingleEntry(userName);

                    if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intentLogin = new Intent(
                                getApplicationContext(), Home.class);

                        intentLogin.putExtra("User_ID", userName);
                        startActivity(intentLogin);

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "User Name and Password do not match",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            });


    }



   /* public void LogIn(View V)
    {

        final Dialog dialog =  new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dialog.setTitle("LUBA LogIn");

        final EditText userID=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.userIDEditText);
        final EditText pass=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText); 

        Button login = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

        final TextView forgotPass=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordTextView);
        final TextView createAcc= (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.createAccountTextView);


        //Set On ClickListener
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                String userName= userID.getText().toString();
                String password=pass.getText().toString();

                String storedPassword = loginDataBaseAdapter.getSingleEntry(userName);

                if(password.equals(storedPassword))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intentLogin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);

                 intentLogin.putExtra("User_ID", userName);
                 startActivity(intentLogin);

                }
                else
                {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name and Password do not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
*/


    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();

    }


}
```

this is the activity that tries to access the database:

```
package com.noura.luba;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter {

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "seniorLUBA";
       static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

       public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;

       public SQLiteDatabase db;
       private final Context context;

       private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

       public LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context)
       {

           context = _context;
           dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);

       }

       public LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException
       {
           db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
           return this;
       }

       public void close()
       {
           db.close();
       }

       public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
       {
           return db;
       }

       public void insertEntry(String password)
       {

           ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
           newValues.put("StdPass", password);

           db.insert("student", null, newValues);
           Toast.makeText(context,  "User Info Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }

       public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
       {

           String where="StdId="+UserName;
           int numberOFEntriesDeleted = db.delete("student", where, new String[]{UserName});
           Toast.makeText(context, "Number of Entry Deleted Successfully : " +numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
       }

       public String getSingleEntry(String userName)
       {


          Cursor cursor=db.query("student", null, "StdID="+userName, new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
           if(cursor.getCount()<1)
               return "DOES NOT EXIST";
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("StdPass"));
           return password;
       }

       public String getSecretInfo(String SecretInfo){

           Cursor cursor=db.query("student", null, "StdID="+SecretInfo, new String[]{SecretInfo}, null, null, null);
           if(cursor.getCount()<1)
               return "Does Not Exist";
           else return SecretInfo;


       }



public void updateEntry(String userName, String password)
{
    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();

    updatedValues.put("StdID", userName);
    updatedValues.put("StdPass", password);

    String where="StdID="+userName;
    db.update("student", updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});
}
}
```

this is the databaseHelper

```
package com.noura.luba;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/noura/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "seniorLUBA";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;


    public DataBaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            copyDataBase();

        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exists to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB= null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch(SQLiteException e) {
            //database doesn't exist yet
        }

        if (checkDB !=null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies my database from my local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * @throws IOException 
     * */

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        //Open my local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        //Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);

        }

        //close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();
    }

    @Override
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) 
        {
         // _db.execSQL(LoginDataBaseAdapter.DATABASE_NAME);

        }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion)
    {

        Log.w("TaskDBAdapter","Upgrading from version" +_oldVersion + "to" +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");

        onCreate(_db);

    }



}
```

this is the logcat:

```
    11-16 22:36:29.076: W/ApplicationPackageManager(28412): getCSCPackageItemText()
11-16 22:36:29.116: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(28412): Parent view is not a TextView
11-16 22:36:29.246: I/Adreno-EGL(28412): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
11-16 22:36:29.246: I/Adreno-EGL(28412): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.07
11-16 22:36:29.246: I/Adreno-EGL(28412): Build Date: 01/22/14 Wed
11-16 22:36:29.246: I/Adreno-EGL(28412): Local Branch: base_au149_adreno_au169_patches
11-16 22:36:29.246: I/Adreno-EGL(28412): Remote Branch: 
11-16 22:36:29.246: I/Adreno-EGL(28412): Local Patches: 
11-16 22:36:29.246: I/Adreno-EGL(28412): Reconstruct Branch: 
11-16 22:36:29.296: D/OpenGLRenderer(28412): Enabling debug mode 0
11-16 22:36:42.636: E/SQLiteLog(28412): (1) no such table: student
11-16 22:36:42.636: D/AndroidRuntime(28412): Shutting down VM
11-16 22:36:42.636: W/dalvikvm(28412): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e66da0)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412): Process: com.noura.luba, PID: 28412
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: student (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM student WHERE StdID=20121400
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1121)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:694)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1436)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1283)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1154)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1322)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at com.noura.luba.LoginDataBaseAdapter.getSingleEntry(LoginDataBaseAdapter.java:70)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at com.noura.luba.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:80)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4626)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19293)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
11-16 22:36:42.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28412):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-16 22:36:43.866: I/Process(28412): Sending signal. PID: 28412 SIG: 9
```

Could anyone point out what the problem might be? and how can i make sure that the copied database in my project is full ?

**Edit**

logcat:

```
11-18 01:27:04.235: W/KeyCharacterMap(427): No keyboard for id 0
11-18 01:27:04.235: W/KeyCharacterMap(427): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
11-18 01:27:15.595: D/AndroidRuntime(427): Shutting down VM
11-18 01:27:15.595: W/dalvikvm(427): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x2ff2a0
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_bind_string(Native Method)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:244)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.bindString(SQLiteQuery.java:185)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:48)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1235)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1189)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1271)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at com.noura.luba.LoginDataBaseAdapter.getSingleEntry(LoginDataBaseAdapter.java:70)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at com.noura.luba.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:80)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-18 01:27:15.615: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-18 01:27:19.587: I/Process(427): Sending signal. PID: 427 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please post some code which you tried to copy database from assets folder..

Comment: @bachu i've added it to the question, please check it out

Comment: what result you are getting when querying through command line.? select * from student;

Comment: i get all the data of that table previously entered into the database

Comment: @bachu apparently the name of the table has a space at the end... that's why it couldn't find it
i've resolved the table not found, however i've encountered another problem... but i can't understand the logcat can you review it please? i will add it below [Edit]

Comment: @bachu that didn't work, i'll add the logcat to your answer so that you can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was adding space to the name of the table student

```
package com.noura.luba;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter {

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "seniorLUBA.db";
       static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

       public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;

       public SQLiteDatabase db;
       private final Context context;

       private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

       public LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context)
       {

           context = _context;
           dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);

       }

       public LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException
       {
           db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
           return this;
       }

       public void close()
       {
           db.close();
       }

       public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
       {
           return db;
       }

       public void insertEntry(String password)
       {

           ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
           newValues.put("StdPass", password);

           db.insert("student ", null, newValues);
           Toast.makeText(context,  "User Info Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }

       public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
       {

           String where="StdId="+UserName;
           int numberOFEntriesDeleted = db.delete("student ", where, new String[]{UserName});
           Toast.makeText(context, "Number of Entry Deleted Successfully : " +numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
       }

       public String getSingleEntry(String userName)
       {


          Cursor cursor=db.query("student ", null, "StdID="+userName, new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
           if(cursor.getCount()<1)
               return "DOES NOT EXIST";
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("StdPass"));
           return password;
       }

       public String getSecretInfo(String SecretInfo){

           Cursor cursor=db.query("student ", null, "StdID="+SecretInfo, new String[]{SecretInfo}, null, null, null);
           if(cursor.getCount()<1)
               return "Does Not Exist";
           else return SecretInfo;


       }



public void updateEntry(String userName, String password)
{
    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();

    updatedValues.put("StdID", userName);
    updatedValues.put("StdPass", password);

    String where="StdID="+userName;
    db.update("student ", updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});
}
}
```